# Angular ui-router: onEnter function is not firing when new state is entered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to learn ui-router, and angular, doing so by building the usual todo app.

My stateprovider code looks like so:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $stateProvider
        .state('alltasks', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: '/templates/tpl.alltasks.html',
            controller: 'TasksCtrl'
        })
        .state('addtask', {
            url: '/add',
            template: 'test',
            onEnter: function () {
                console.log('entered projects add state');
            }
        });
}]);
```

I expected the console.log to fire when I enter the addtask state, but it does not.

Comment: are you sure your browser has `#/add` in url

Comment: @GPicazo : Thanks to your example, I was able to find my mistakes:

1. My links were outside the tag with ng-app
2. I had used href='#add' insead of ui-sref

The code now works. If you post your answer I will accept it. 

Again thanks for the time you msut have spent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with the code you posted. Here is a working plunkr that you can compare to: plnkr.co/edit/GMfwVYXIXM2p7kkQU1Xj?p=preview . In particular, you may want to check your library versions and that you are actually linking/navigating to the addtask state.

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time :-) .